# Magento2 - Get "Sort By" value in catalog search page

Tags: magento2, catalogsearch

How get **Sort By** value **Relevance** in this page.

Using `$productListToolbar` return only price, name, position value, but I need relevance.

Attached the Screenshot here.
[image: mag]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to use the below plugin
**File: Custom\Relevance\etc\frontend\di.xml**

```
<type name="Magento\CatalogSearch\Block\Result">
        <plugin name="Custom_Relevance::getRelvance" type="Custom\Relevance\Plugin\Search\Block\Result" sortOrder="101"/>
</type>
```

**File: Custom\Relevance\Plugin\Search\Block.php**

```
<?php
namespace Custom\Relevance\Plugin\Search\Block;

use Magento\Framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock;
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context as Context;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\Resolver as LayerResolver;
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template as ViewTemplate;
use Magento\Search\Model\QueryFactory;

class Result extends ViewTemplate
{
    public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        LayerResolver $layerResolver,
        QueryFactory $queryFactory,
        array $data =[]
    )
    {
        $this->_catalogLayer = $layerResolver->get();
        $this->_queryFactory = $queryFactory;

        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }

    public function afterSetListOrders() {

        /* @var $query \Magento\Search\Model\Query */
        //$query = $this->_queryFactory->get();
        //$queryText = $query->getQueryText();


        $category = $this->catalogLayer->getCurrentCategory();
        /* @var $category \Magento\Catalog\Model\Category */
        $availableOrders = $category->getAvailableSortByOptions();
        unset($availableOrders['position']);
        $availableOrders['relevance'] = __('Relevance');


    $directionToSet = 'desc';
        $defaultSortBy = 'relevance';        

        $this->getLayout()->getBlock('search_result_list')->setAvailableOrders(
            $availableOrders
        )->setDefaultDirection(
            $directionToSet
        )->setDefaultSortBy(
            $defaultSortBy
        );
        return $this;

    }
}
```

**Second approach if above not works, using Toolbar**

you can implement plugin on the class

`\Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Toolbar` and method

```
public function afterGetCurrentOrder() {
    $orders = $this->getAvailableOrders();
        echo '<pre>'; print_r($orders); echo '</pre>';
}
```

this will give all the sort orders something like below.

```
Array (
    [name] => Product Name
    [price] => Price
    [manufacturer] => Manufacturer
    [relevance] => Magento\Framework\Phrase Object
        (
            [text:Magento\Framework\Phrase:private] => Relevance
            [arguments:Magento\Framework\Phrase:private] => Array
                (
                )

        )

)
```